# Is there a way I can combine these two methods?

Tags: java, methods, data-structures, linked-list, overloading

Currently I'm creating a method to reverse a linkedlist in java, but it requires two methods:

```
public void reverse(){
    reverse(head);
}

private void reverse(Node h){
    if(h.next==null){
        System.out.print(h.data+" ");
        return;
    }

    reverse(h.next);
    System.out.print(h.data+" ");   
}
```

This way I call the reverse method with 0 parameters, which then calls the other reverse method. Is there any way to make them 1 method without changing the other aspects of my LinkedList class?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: call `reverse(head)` directly, make the method public, so it will be accessible.

Comment: It is better as two methods. It is very common to have a public method calling a private recursive method with extra parameter(s).

Comment: @YoungHobbit my main class doesn't have access to the head node.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Really, I never knew that. It seems kind of odd to me.

Comment: @idude Then It is fine like this and there is nothing wrong with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very common to have a public method calling a private recursive method with extra parameter(s). See the source code for [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java) for an example of this.

However, in your case it may be better to avoid recursion completely. One problem with recursion is that you are only able to nest method calls to a certain depth before you get a `StackOverflowError`.

An alternative is to use loops instead. The following would work:

```
public void reverse(){
    List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Node n = head; n != null; n = n.next)
        nodes.add(n);
    for (int i = nodes.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        System.out.print(nodes.get(i).data + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Technically, there is a way, but I would not recommend it.  This is it:

```
public void reverse( Node... nodes )
{
    Node h;
    if( nodes.length == 0 )
        h = head;
    else
    {
        assert nodes.length == 1;
        h = nodes[0];
    }

    if( h.next == null )
    {
        System.out.print( h.data + " " );
        return;
    }

    reverse( h.next );
    System.out.print( h.data + " " );   
}
```

Note that this would also require making class `Node` public, which is ***also*** not a good idea.  (Or you might just get a warning for having a public method accepting a parameter of a private type, which you can then suppress; I don't remember.)

But Paul Boddington's comment is right on the money.

Answer (score 2):

Paul beat me to a similar answer, but I figured I'd post mine anyways since I assumed that you do not want to use ArrayList as a dependency:

Yes it is possible.  If it is a doubly linked list you could traverse the list to the last node then walk the list to the front. However, I will also assume it's a single linked list, so I'll answer using an array to store all node references. Also, I assume you have another method to calculate length.

```
public void reverse() {
    int length = length();
    Node [] nodes = new Node[length];
    Node currentNode = head;

    int i = 0;
    // Populate the array
    while(currentNode != null)
    {
        nodes[i] = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
        i++;
    }

    // Iterate backwards to print the array
    for(int j = length -1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        System.out.println(nodes[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can make the parameter in your displayed second method "act" as an Optional Parameter. In the method declaration below we're in essence making the Node Type parameter to be an Node array which can be passed as empty. Since we're only need to pass 1 parameter to our method then we only need the supplied Node data contained in the element Index of 0 (the first element of the array).

Within the method itself we declare a Node variable which was the same type and name as what your parameter was so to eliminate any confusion within the code body of the method and we provide a **default** of 0 (default can be whatever you want). We then check the new headerInfo[] array parameter to see if there was anything supplied and if there was then we apply that data from the first element of the headerInfo[] array (since we're only using one parameter for this method) to the new Node type variable **h**. The **args[]** parameter for the **main** method in a class does the same thing.

```
public void reverse(Node... headerInfo){
    Node h = 0;
    if (headerinfo.length != 0) { h = headerInfo[0]; } 

    if(h.next==null){
        System.out.print(h.data+" ");
        return;
    }

    reverse(h.next);
    System.out.print(h.data+" ");   
}
```

Now the method can be can be called as reverse() or reverse(head)

EDIT:

Whops...Mike beat me to it :)